# Try-with-resource / Closable-Autoclosable

Tags: java

I’m trying to understand **Try-with-resource**. After reading few articles, I understand that each class who implement or extend closable/auto-closable can benefit from the `close()` method which is called to close the object.

Now in practice I have this code:

```
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(instructionFile);
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String startingPosition = sc.nextLine();
        String instructions = sc.nextLine();
        // Some actions
    }
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    throw new IncompleteInstructions();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw e;
}
```

As you can see, I used `FileInputStream` and `Scanner` classes, I was expecting to see both of those class implements or extends `Closable`, instead I have the classic method `close()`, seems to be a wrap of `Closable`.

My question, who should implement or extend `Closable`, is it the source of data, like files for `FileInputStream` class and Readable interface for the `Scanner` class.

Thanks you !

Comment: Both classes that access resources, [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) implement [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) and [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). The latter is needed for a `try` with resources because it closes them automatically when its scope is left.

Comment: @deHaar last part is not true. `Closeable` interface extends `AutoCloseable`

Comment: @Amongalen OK, since when, has it always been like that? Well, I removed the wrong part anyway.

Comment: @deHaar no idea since when, just now checked the [javadocs for Closeable in java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)

Comment: OK, to be targeting the question then: Classes that are accessing resources implement `Closeable` and thus `AutoCloseable`, too. The files or any object that is actually accessed by such a Java class does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileInputStream` extends `InputeStream`

`InputStream` and `Scanner` both implement `Closable`

`Closable` extends `AutoClosable`

So `FileInputStream` and `Scanner` instances are `AutoClosable` and after the instructions in the try block finish the execution, JVM will automatically call `.close()` method on those resources. As [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) state,

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed
> at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your classes implements `Closeable` which extends `AutoCloseable`.

Reading their javadoc helps but, in the end, their `close` method will be automatically called by the try-with-resources.

[`AutoCloseable` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html):

> An object that may hold resources (such as file or socket handles) until it is closed. The `close()` method of an `AutoCloseable` object is called automatically when exiting a `try`-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in the resource specification header. This construction ensures prompt release, avoiding resource exhaustion exceptions and errors that may otherwise occur.